# Artikelgebrauch "Wir machen den Salat und kaufen die Getränke."

Tags: article

In einem Lehrwerk steht folgende Aufgabe:

*Mario und Elena planen eine Grillparty. Hören und lesen Sie das Gespräch. Schreiben Sie die Einkaufsliste für Mario und Elena.*

Der Dialog beginnt folgendermaßen:

> - Wir machen den Salat und kaufen die Getränke. Und Katrin und Lukas kaufen das Fleisch und die Würstchen.

Ich habe Schwierigkeiten beim Verständnis des Artikelgebrauchs:

a) Warum wird "Salat" mit dem bestimmten Artikel verwendet? Warum nicht „Wir machen einen Salat.“?

b) Warum werden „Getränke“ und „Würstchen“ mit dem bestimmten Artikel gebraucht? Kann man etwa nicht ohne Artikel auskommen, wenn es um unbestimmte "Getränke" und "Würstchen" im Plural geht?

Es geht weiter:

> - Ich gehe zum Markt und kaufe die Eier, die Tomaten und die Gurke.

Mir wurde beigebracht, dass es keinen unbestimmten Artikel im Plural gibt. Der Lehrer gab uns damals ein Beispiel „wenn wir zum Bäcker gehen, kaufen wir Brötchen und nicht DIE (drei bestimmten) Brötchen unten links“. Deshalb hat es mich stutzig gemacht, dass gleich zu Beginn des Dialogs, ohne dass es vorhin erwähnt wurde, um welche Getränke es sich handelt, der bestimmte Artikel verwendet wurde. Ist es tatsächlich richtig oder ist es so nur, weil in diesem Kapitel das Thema "Artikel im Deutschen" eingeführt wird?

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Was hast Du gegen die Verwendung von bestimmten Artikeln? _"Seriously?!? Warum nicht "Nullartikel"? Ist es tatsächlich richtig oder ist es so nur, weil in diesem Kapitel das Thema "Artikel im Deutschen" eingeführt wird?"_ Nein, das ist im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch durchaus so üblich und auch richtig. Ich verstehe Deine Zweifel nicht. Könntest Du Deine Frage bitte dahingehend ergänzen, was genau Dich zweifeln lässt?

Comment: Es geht eben nicht um unbestimmte Getränke und Würstchen. Es geht um die Würstchen und die Getränke für die Party.

Comment: Auch hier gilt: Es sind nicht irgendwelche Getränke, sondern die für die Party.

Comment: @Serena: Ich habe keinen Zweifel an Frust/Unverständnis. Es ist nur so, dass die Frage für sich stehen soll und jemand, der sie in 2 Jahren liest, die Anhäufung von Satzzeichen etc. einfach ... nicht nachempfinden kann. Und es hier auch nicht um einen Meinungsaustausch geht - sondern nur um das nackte "ich verstehe xy nicht, an abc hatte ich gedacht, wieso ist rst hier richtig/falsch?". Und daher mein Vorschlag, diesen kleinen Teil in der Frage die beim Schreiben vorhandenen Emotionen zu streichen um die Frage besser zu machen. Ja, ich kann die Frage auch editieren - war nicht meine Prio 1.

Comment: Übrigens gibt es im Bairischen/Österreichischen sehr wohl unbestimmte Artikel im Plural: _sie kafm **ane** Wiaschtln_. Aber ausschließlich dialektal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Durch den Gebrauch des bestimmten Artikels wird hervorgehoben, dass es nicht um irgendwelchen Salat und irgendwelche Getränke geht, sondern um den Salat und die Getränke für die Party.

Würde der unbestimmte Artikel oder kein Artikel verwendet, würde man zwar aus dem Kontext schließen, dass Salat und Getränke für die Party bestimmt sind. Es könnte aber auch anders sein. Z.B.

> Morgen ist die Grillparty. Wir machen einen Salat. Den essen wir selbst auf und kaufen einen für die Party.

Comment: Vielen Dank für Deine Hilfe! Ich verstehe =) Eine kurze Frage noch: wenn die Kursteilnehmer eine Einkaufsliste erstellen, müssen sie dann die Lebensmittel für den Salat bzw. für die Party mit dem bestimmten Artikel verwenden?

Comment: Im Kontext einer Einkaufsliste ist es egal, wofür die Waren bestimmt sind. Deswegen und um weniger schreiben zu müssen wird man den Artikel weglassen.

Comment: viiielen Dank! really appreciate it!

Comment: @Serena eine reale Einkaufsliste würde statt Artikeln eher Mengenangaben in Zahlen-/Ziffernform enthalten, zum Beispiel: *2 Eier; 1 Flasche Cola*.